# How to make xCode "act" as the most normal editors?

Tags: xcode, macos

I wonder, why doesn't xCode "act" as a normal editor? For example, when I press `Ctrl+X`, I'd like the current line to be copied-cut. When I press `Shift+Tab` I'd like the current selection to be shifted to the left, etc. That's the stuff most editors do by default.

How to make it do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Preferences -> Key Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-keybindings_preferences/articles/viewing_keyboard_shortcuts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010351-CH1-SW1). Here you get a list of actions and their keyboard shortcuts - and you can change those keyboard shortcuts!

It's quite amazing how many actions there are, including a great number of familiar Emacs actions such as mark and yank. Many of them have no corresponding menu item; many of them have no keyboard shortcut by default. Some of them may be the things you are looking for, and all you need to do is change the shortcut if you don't like it. It is very possible that you'll find at least some bindings that you can use to make Xcode behave in a more familiar way.

Comment: Also it is possible to define a custom set of keyboard shortcuts as a file, and you can find many third-party mods, such as the [XVim plug-in](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim).

Comment: What amazing it is to define all of them by myself.